# How to Get Available Disk Space *IN A FOLDER* from Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to send alert notifications if the disk in which I store log files reaches 75% capacity. However, everything I've seen on SO and other sites with respect to Java show how to get available disk space by supplying the name of a partition (e.g. a drive letter in Windows). However, this is of no help in a world where symbolic links exist (Linux and Windows with NTFS); in production, [tomcat path]\logs is pretty much guaranteed NOT to exist on the same physical machine as [tomcat path]\webapps, [tomcat path]\conf, etc.

Therefore, I need to find out how much physical space remains on whatever storage is symbolically connected to the "[tomcat path]\logs" folder on an NTFS-based Windows system (though, obviously, a system-independent method would be preferred).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [FileStore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) for the directory:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir"));
dir = dir.toRealPath();

FileStore fs = Files.getFileStore(dir);
```

The FileStore class has methods for examining the space on the storage device or file system it represents.  (It’s a bit confusing;  the FileStore class represents a file system, but the FileSystem class actually represents a set of file systems acting as a single hierarchy.)

```
long freeSpace = fs.getUsableSpace();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to roll your own alerting system.

I would use a ***rolling file appender*** and make sure never to face a full disk because of the logs.

In a more complicated scenario, splitting the logs into "Very important transactions", "Critical Errors" and "Everything else" makes sense.

Collecting logs with sth like Logstash and Filebeat if you have to keep them for a longer time and monitoring the log collector space with Prometheus and Grafana would be a sensible solution. Prometheus would manage the alerting for you.

The rest of the logs just let them roll...

I hope it helps.